# Vega-lite heatmap "transform" isn't working right

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, heatmap, vega, vega-lite

1) There's a X - coordinate and  Y - coordinate. There's a Z - value. Z needs to calculate AVG.

```
"data": {
"values": [
  {"x": 0, "y": 0, "z": 0},
  {"x": 1, "y": 0, "z": 1},
  {"x": 2, "y": 0, "z": 5},
  {"x": 2, "y": 0, "z": 10},
  {"x": 4, "y": 0, "z": 16},
  {"x": 0, "y": 1, "z": 1},
  {"x": 1, "y": 1, "z": 2},
  {"x": 2, "y": 1, "z": 5},
  {"x": 3, "y": 1, "z": 10},
  {"x": 5, "y": 1, "z": 26}
]},
```

If the data:

```
"encoding": {
"x": {"field": "x", "type": "ordinal", "title": "X"},
"y": {"field": "y", "type": "ordinal", "title": "Y"} },
```

then AVG that's right:

[Vega Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-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-iezi-aTqdiuvn7PbuSztM0eAAyoxyl7pG0fEcRPe7rmFUrCzvG3DkKf7JYkhSMkT2pGd9G4MtYwPRJkkDdhI3gVNN2yZCwG3YtID3f850DECdVRKlr1vAIHyOF8+zffMPwrRtwjwg9m1bWh2zJTsY2bXtq2dWsbndT0yQAR1YJFzWic0qB0as0Qwal2ToVxDDtFdyQg8toMAuCEKQ4tUPQ78sIPHDgN-M8pMIm871IswRhGMBtAiB5-gwuV32VGjaJ-P8GJbdNmMDRVYHNeUsy4+kePaPijygISROYKJGAksCVMg-8YKA9l4PQRDQw3GpN2hIIgA)

[image]

If I use "transform" with  "groupby"  :

```
"transform": [  {"window": [{"op": "count", "field": "x", "as": "x2"}], "groupby": ["y"]}],
"encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "x2", "type": "ordinal", "title": "X"},
    "y": {"field": "y", "type": "ordinal", "title": "Y"} 
 },
```

then AVG it's not true: 
[Vega Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-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-iezi-aTqdicM9ZPbuSztM0eAAyoxyl7pG0fEcRPe7rmFUrCzvG3DkKf7JYkhSY9f2pGd9G4MtYwPRJkkDdhI3gVNN2yZCwG3YtID3f850DE8z2rC9r1vAIHyOF8+zffMPwrRtwjw-9m1bWh2zJTsY2bXtqxdWsbg9ed2QAR1YJE8GYKJGCoHQCPRKIyToVxDHtFdyQg8toMAuCEKQ4tUPQ78sIPHDgL-MpUSpIi71IswRhGMBtAiB5-gwuV32VGjaJ-P8D0Y9NmMDRVYFE+Usy4+kePaPjAyEkSxNEySwJUyD-xgoD2Xg9BENDDcak3aEgiAA)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The transform is doing exactly what you're telling it to do:

```
{"window": [{"op": "count", "field": "x", "as": "x2"}], "groupby": ["y"]}
```

It groups your data by `y`. Schematically it looks like this:

```
y=0: x: [0,  1,  2,  2,  4]
     z: [0,  1,  5, 10, 16]

y=1: x: [0,  1,  2,  3, 5]
     z: [1,  2,  5, 10, 26]
```

Then it does a sliding window and assigns the count to `x2`:

```
y=0: x:  [0,  1,  2,  2,  4]
     z:  [0,  1,  5, 10, 16]
     x2: [1,  2,  3,  4,  5]

y=1: x:  [0,  1,  2,  3,  5]
     z:  [1,  2,  5, 10, 26]
     x2: [1,  2,  3,  4,  5]
```

As you can see, when you create a plot of `y` vs `x2`, there is now a single `z` value at each location, and this is correctly reflected in the chart that you show above.

If you want different behavior, you should specify a different transform.